# Next step to take to reach the contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

This problem is from Discrete Math and its Applications
[image]

I am trying to use proof by contradiction to do this problem, proof by contradiction as described by the book

[image]

Here is my work so far for this problem [image]

What I did was i formed a proposition p that represents the problem at hand - there is no positive integer n such that n^2 + n^3 = 100. This is a proposition because it has a true/false value - there either is this positive integer or there isn't. From my understanding of proof by contradiction, I am supposed to assume that ~p(not p) is  true, meaning there is a positive integer n such that n^2 + n^3 = 100 and show that this will lead to a contradiction(proposition that is always false no matter what input values are). If it does lead to a contradiction, the proposition ~(p) is false, meaning p is true. I am tried to do this by first factoring out a n^2, getting n^2(n+1) = 100. What step do i take next to prove this expression is a contradiction(false, no matter what value n is passe in)? I can't use the quadratic formula because there is a n cubed in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are near.

**Hint:** Use that $n$ is positive integer. What can be $n$ if you know that $n^2$ divides $100$?

Comment: Does n^2 divides 100 mean that it can be divided by 100 to form an integer?

Comment: You have $n^2(n+1)=100$, so $n^2\,|\,100$. Therefore $n$ can only be $1,2,5$ or $10$.

Comment: By definition of m divides n, there is some integer k such that n = k * m. Based off that, you would go through all those  cases and show that that for each case, (k*n^2), k is not n + 1?

Comment: And your final conclusion would be - Let's assume there exists there an integer n such that n^2 + n^3 = 100. We use algebra to reduce that expression to n^2(1 + n) = 100. This means that n^2 divides 100, meaning that there is some integer k such that 100 = k* n^2. The integer k in this case would be 1 + n. Because n^2 divides 100, n can only be in the set of positive integers {1, 2, 5, 10}. For each positive integer in that set, it turns out that the integer k is not 1 + n. Therefore we have arrived at a contradiction. Does everything look right?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Remember that $n$ is an integer, this means that $n$ is either even or odd. If $a*b=100$, and $a, b\in \mathbb{N}$, what do you know about $a$ and $b$ (regarding whether they are even or odd)?

Comment: that n and n+1 both have to be even

Comment: Right. In other words: CONTRADICTION! (How I love this way of proving things)

Comment: so ~p is a contradiction? Or does ~p lead to a contradiction?

Comment: ~p leads to a contradiction. Thus ~p is not true, which means that ~~p must be true (aka p)

Comment: oh cause of what i said earlier, either this positive integer exists or it doesn't

Comment: Exactly! And since it is apparently impossible for one to exist (because of the proof), such an integer does not exist.

Comment: So in English, would this be if there was a real integer n such that n^2 + n^3 = 100, n and n + 1 would both have to be even. Therefore there cannot be this real integer n because a number added by 1 must change parity?

Comment: Yup. Just say $n$ instead of 'real integer' $n$, since this causes confusion as to whether $n$ belongs to the reals or the integers.

Comment: Yeah just the implication part is confusion. Just from ~p, you infer something false(number added by 1 does not change parity), meaning the whole implication is wrong?

Comment: It's basically the following: Let's assume that there exists an integer $n$, such that $n^2+n^3=100$. Then $n$ would need to be both odd and even at the same time, which is impossible. This means that no such $n$ can therefore exist, because no $n$ exists that is both even and odd.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot more sense. I don't know why i was trying to involve implications....

Comment: Now that i think it about it, odd * even = even so you don't really know anything about a or b. You know one of the two is even but the other is odd or even. So technically n could be even and n + 1 could be odd

Comment: I thought 5*20=100