# Would it be necessary to have another proof within the proof by cases in this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

[image]

I am using Proof by Cases. This is my book's definition on it.
[image]

Here is my work so far [image]

I tried to leverage without of generality as Michael Cromer said [Next step to take in this proof by contradiction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114483/next-step-to-take-in-this-proof-by-contradiction/1114492?noredirect=1#comment2275670_1114492), if x + y = y + x, you don't need to test (x,y) and (y,x). Here's where my first question shows up. Would I need to prove that the abs(x) + abs(y) = abs(y) + abs(x) ? I didn't need to prove x + y = y + x because thats an established mathematical law - http://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html

So going off the fact that I didn't need to prove that, my cases were by nonnegativity, if both nonnegative, one is nonnegative, or both are negative. I primarily leveraged without loss of generality in the one nonnegative case, it was the same regardless if x is nonnegative or y is nonnegative

My next question was do i need to prove all of the conclusions I received from my cases. For something like abs(x) + abs(y) = abs(x + y), I just intuitively know that they are the same if both are non negative. Would I need to prove this? Same with the other cases. I wasn't sure it that be overkill or be necessary for this proof.

Comment: Someone explain the downvote? I always try to put a lot of thought into these questions.

Comment: The overall structure of the proof is fine. I might make a separate case where $x \geq 0$ and $y < 0$ and explain at that point that that case doesn't need to be discussed for the reasons you mentioned. The main problem with this proof is that you don't give enough detail within the cases. It would be clearest if within each case, you removed the absolute values as much as possible. As it stands, the proof can't be called correct, because it avoids discussing most of the difficulties.